# Compare cosine similarity of word with BERT model

Tags: python, nlp, gensim, bert-language-model, word-embedding

Hi I am looking to generate similar words for a word using BERT model, the same approach we use in gensim to generate most_similar word, I found the approach as:

```
from transformers import BertTokenizer, BertModel

import torch

tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')

model = BertModel.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')

word = "Hello"

inputs = tokenizer(word, return_tensors="pt")

outputs = model(**inputs)

word_vect = outputs.pooler_output.detach().numpy()
```

Okay, now this gives me the embedding for input word given by user, so can we compare this embedding with complete BERT model for cosine similarity to find top N embeddings that are closest match with that word, and then convert the embeddings to word using the vocab.txt file in the model? is it possible?

Comment: BERT isn't a bag-of-words model like the Word2Vec model used by Gensim, so you can't just retrieve similar words from the model itself. You could retrieve the vector representations of multiple words and establish proximity with cosine similarity or euclidean distance.

Comment: oh okay, you mean I can only get vectors of words from the bert model and than I can compare it to find similar word.. So to find something similar like that I have to get a dataset and save the indexes of word and embeddings generated from bert and then apply cosine similarity??

Comment: Exactly! But given your purpose I'd advise just using Gensim. BERT is a context-aware model, ie it processes the semantic context of a words (in a sentence). Since you'll only be processing single words, Gensim will suffice.

Comment: okay, yes I am using gensim currently with glove-wiki model, the result sometime not good so exploring other options also the pretrained model can not be retrained in that. Do you know any alternate gensim model that covers wide variety or words with good similar word, that can help me??

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you need to store embeddings for all word from your vocabulary.
After that, you can use some tools to find the closest embedding to the target embedding.
For example, you can use [NearestNeighbors](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.NearestNeighbors.html#sklearn.neighbors.NearestNeighbors) from scikit-learn.
Another option you might like to consider is HNSW, which is the data structure specially designed to perform fast approximate nearest neighbour search. [Faiss](https://faiss.ai/) is a quite good implementation of HNSW by Facebook.

Comment: oh okay, so I can not get embeddings from the bert model itself, I must have a dataset for which I will get the embeddings and than find the similar words using matching algorithm you mentioned? right

Comment: One thing I'd bear in mind is dataset size, HNSW is definitely the way to go for large datasets, if you have 1M+ vectors/tokens to compare for example - but if you're in the <100K range, you can get by with a simple FlatL2 or FlatIP index (adding IVF if you want) with better accuracy and the same speeds